# pageReference behaves differently in classic and lightning

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have a VF page with a button. When the button is clicked, I would like a new tab to be open for the defined URL. At the same time, I would like the original VF page to remain at its original state.
Currently, I am experiencing different behavior in classic and lightning.
Lightning - A new Tab is open for the new page, but my original page gets reset.
Classic - The current tab is overwritten with the new page.

Here is my code:
VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" value="Report Duplicates" action="{!reportDuplicates}" />
```

Controller:

```
public pageReference reportDuplicates(){

     pageReference reportDups = new PageReference('https://google.com'
     reportDups.setRedirect(true);
     return reportDups;
}
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. Have to use:
<apex:commandlink action="{!reportDuplicates}" target="_blank">